# Как занести данные из БД в строковый массив?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой `php` код:

```
if ($_POST["parentid"] == "0") {
    echo json_encode(array("0" => "Москва", "1" => "Санкт-Петербург"));
} elseif ($_POST["parentid"] == "1") {
    echo json_encode(array("2" => "Киев", "3" => "Одесса"));
}
```

надо сделать запрос в таблицу БД по `$_POST["parenid"]` и полученные результаты преобразовать в такой же вид

Comment: В чем проблема? Где не получается? Покажите что у вас уже имеется

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subsidiarycat WHERE parent_id='$_POST[parentid]'");   
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      echo json_encode($arr);

Comment: не возвращает результат

Answer (score 0):

Не позволяйте POST-дате попадать в Ваши запросы, иначе даете другим возможность для инъекций. Убедитесь, что данные в таблице `subsidiarycat` с выбранным значением parent_id существуют.

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("host", "login", "password", "database");
    $parentId = 0;
    switch($_POST['parentid']) {
        case "1":
            $parentId = 1;
            break;
        case "2":
            $parentId = 2;
            break;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM subsidiarycat WHERE parent_id = '$parentId'"); 
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: я пишу на php 5.6, данные в таблице существуют, я пытался вручную составить ассоциативный массив через циклы, но не вышло